# Not able to load skyboxImage using model_viewer_plus

Tags: flutter, dart, 3d

This is the code. I have tried to implement it using model_viewer_plus, but it seems to not work for implementing skyboxImage no matter what.I have used a custom made appbar here, so please change it to a normal one if you are trying to run the code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:model_viewer_plus/model_viewer_plus.dart';

import '../component/appbar.dart';

class RaveScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RaveScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<RaveScreen> createState() => _RaveScreenState();
}

class _RaveScreenState extends State<RaveScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBarToHome(context, "RAVE"),
      body: const SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Center(child: Text("RAPTEE DINO")),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 500, // Adjust the height of the ModelViewer as needed
              child: ModelViewer(
                src: 'assets/car2.glb',
                animationCrossfadeDuration: 300,
                alt: 'DINO',
                id: "reveal",
                cameraOrbit: "360deg 90deg 1.5m",
                maxCameraOrbit: "infinity 90deg 2 bm",
                minCameraOrbit: "infinity 20deg 1m",
                loading: Loading.auto,
                autoRotate: true,
                cameraControls: true,
                touchAction: TouchAction.panY,
                orbitSensitivity: 1,
                rotationPerSecond: "5deg",
                shadowIntensity: 1,
                shadowSoftness: 1,
                autoRotateDelay: 0,
                debugLogging: false,
                disablePan: true,
                skyboxImage: "assets/sky.jpg"
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```